# jQuery - selecting a set of links which hrefs end with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I select links that end with ".jpg", ".gif", "png", but only the ones from inside a certain DIV?

like

```
<div class="stuff_to_select">
  <a href="foo.jpg"> ... </a>
  <a href="boo.jpg"> ... </a>
</div>

<div class="stuff_to_ignore">
  <a href="moo.jpg"> ... </a>
  <a href="boo.jpg"> ... </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $links = $('div.stuff_to_select a').filter(function(){
    return !!this.href.match('[\.jpg|\.png|\.gif]$');
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xAt8Q/1/)

Comment: thank you. your code had previously been without `!!` and it also worked. What does `!!` do?

Answer (score 6):

Actually I think the Attribute Ends With Selector would be more appropriate

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

The example below will find all jpg, gif, and png href tags located under div with classname "stuff_to_select"

```
$("div.stuff_to_select a[href$='jpg'],
   div.stuff_to_select a[href$='gif'],
   div.stuff_to_select a[href$='png'],")
```

Comment: Isn't that selector testing the div with class `stuff_to_select` for an href attribute?

Comment: I think that should be `$(".stuff_to_select a[href$='jpg'],...")`

Comment: @Zikes  not placing the div infront of the class name can cause slower preformance.

Answer (score 2):

`$("div.stuff_to_select a[href$='.jpg']")`

Answer (score 2):

```
var jpgs = $('#div_id [href*=".jpg"]');
var gifs = $('#div_id [href*=".gif"]');
var pngs = $('#div_id [href*=".png"]');

var all = $.merge( $.merge(jpgs, gifs), pngs);
```